# what is "PGC-I-0222-Redundant definition for symbol"

Tags: c, ubuntu-16.04, openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

[how to solve pgcc&openacc linker error "__pgi_uacc_multicorestart", "__pgi_uacc_multicoreend"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580080/how-to-solve-pgccopenacc-linker-error-pgi-uacc-multicorestart-pgi-uacc/47637516#47637516)

This is a follow up question after the one above.

In "compile lbe.c to lbe.o message:", I always see the "PGC-I-0222-Redundant definition" message. Is it a warning or error? Why would it happen? How do I fix it?

```
PGC-I-0222-Redundant definition for symbol __THROW (/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h: 74)
PGC-I-0222-Redundant definition for symbol __extension__ (/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h: 358)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are just information messages indicating that the symbols are getting defined twice.  Since it's the same definition for both, it's fine and no need to fix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it unavoidable or there is something in my codes I should change?

Comment: No, it would mean changing system or PGI header files.  Again, it's just an informational message and not something that will cause issues.  Removing the "-Minform" flag will hide these messages.